# Reload React Native Javascript before starting the app?

Tags: android, react-native

I often write Javascript code that crashes my React Native app. When I restart the app, the code runs again and crashes the app. I don't have a chance to reload the Javascript code before it crashes. How can I reload the Javascript code before it runs it?

Right now, I'm just running `react-native run-android` again, which takes a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the React Native Packager. It has an http API and a programatic API too. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/packager